# Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException

Tags: ajax, forms, validation, symfony

I  am trying to set up an ajax call to to fill the select option for user.

1/ You select location

2/ new dropdown appear with zone

Everything work just fine until :

3/ Validation form does not pass

```
Unable to reverse value for property path "zone":

The choice "13e Arrondissement" does not exist or is not unique
```

FormType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    //...

     ->add('location', EntityType::class, ['class' => 'PagesBundle:City'])
     ->add('zone', CoreType\ChoiceType::class, ['choices_as_values' => true, 'mapped' => false]);

    $builder->get('zone')->addEventListener( FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm()->getParent();
            $data = $event->getData();
            $city[$data] = $data;

            $form->add('zone', CoreType\ChoiceType::class, ['choices' => $city,'choices_as_values' => true]);

        //...
```

My Ajax :

```
$("document").ready(function() { 
$('#zone').addClass('uk-hidden');
$("#cityName").change(function() {
    var city = $( "#owner_location option:selected" ).text();

       $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'http://locavip.dev/app_dev.php/owner/city/' + city,

          beforeSend: function(){
            $('#owner_zone option').remove();
          },

          success: function(data) {

             $.each(data.zone, function(index, value){
                $('#zone').removeClass('uk-hidden');
                $("#owner_zone").append($('<option>', { value : value, text: value }));
             });
          }
       });
```

});
});

AjaxController:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $database = 'PagesBundle:'.$city;
        $cityName = $em->getRepository($database)->findAll();   

        foreach ($cityName as $value) {
                $cities[] = $value->getZone();
        }
        $response = new JsonResponse();

        return $response->setData(array('zone' => $cities));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.

For my ajax field "ZONE" i first use ChoiceType::class, then on PRE_SUBMIT i retrieve user data from "ZONE" and i modify my field to to TextType::class then i use "getData()" option to set the right data before inserting into DB.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('type', ApxType\TypeType::class, ['expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false,'label' => false])
        ->add('room', ApxType\NbRoomType::class,['expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false,'label' => false])
        ->add('rent', CoreType\NumberType::class,['label' => false])
        ->add('area', CoreType\NumberType::class,['label' => false])
        ->add('images', CoreType\CollectionType::class, [
                            'entry_type' => ImagesFlatType::class,
                            'allow_add' => true,
                            'required' => false,
                            'allow_delete' => true,
                            'label' => false,
                            'by_reference' => false,
                            ])

        ->add('transport', CoreType\TextType::class,['label' => false, 'required' => false])
        ->add('furnished', ApxType\FurnishedType::class, ['expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false,'label' => false])
        ->add('vip', ApxType\LesVipType::class, ['expanded' => true, 'multiple' => true,'label' => false])
        ->add('feature', ApxType\FeatureType::class, ['expanded' => true, 'multiple' => true,'label' => false])
        ->add('description', CoreType\TextareaType::class,['label' => false, 'required' => false])

        // City with ajax call  in register.js
        ->add('location', EntityType::class, ['class' => 'PagesBundle:City', 'placeholder' => 'Selectionner une ville'])
        ->add('zone', CoreType\ChoiceType::class, ['mapped' => false, 'choices_as_values' => true]);

    // Add listeners
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, array($this, 'onPreSetData'));
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, array($this, 'onPreSubmit'));

    $builder->getForm();
}
/**
 * Check if user is login
 * Add field accordingly 
 * 
 */
public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
{
    $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    if (!is_object($user)) 
    {
        $form->add('user', UsersType::class, ['label' => false])
                ->add('corporate', ApxType\CorporateType::class, ['expanded' => true,
                                                                    'multiple' => false,
                                                                    'label' => false])
                ->add('fee', CoreType\NumberType::class, ['label' => false, 'required' => false]);
    }

    if(is_object($user))
    {
        foreach($user->getOwner() as $value)
        {
            if($value->getCorporate() === 'agence')
            {
                $form->add('fee', CoreType\NumberType::class, ['label' => false, 'required' => false]);
            }
        }   
    }
}

/**
 * Change field type and populate database 
 * 
 */
public function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event)
{
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $data = $event->getData();

    if(!array_key_exists('zone', $data))
    {
        foreach($user->getOwner() as $value)
        {
            $data['zone'] = $value->getZone();
        }

    }

    $city = $data['zone'];

    $form->add('zone', CoreType\TextType::class, ['data' => $city]);
}
```